# Before Delete Trigger

Tags: before-trigger

I started writing the following trigger:
Basically what I am trying to achieve is to prevent deletion of `Parent__c` if it has a `Child__c` attached.

```
    trigger ParentTrigger on Parent__c (before delete) {

    //get all the child objects
    List<Child__c> childList = new List<Child__c> ([SELECT id, Parent__c FROM Child__c]);

   //run through all the parents --> here I need to somehow say that the trigger should apply only to   parents that have children attached    
for (Parent__c par : Trigger.Old) {
        if (childList.size() > 0) {
            par.adderror('Cannot be deleted');
        }
      }
    }
```

Tia.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you make a map of Children by Parent Id rather than a list, so you can check per Parent whether he has a Child. By using a map, you can also show which Children are blocking the deletion. Also, it's a good idea to only retrieve the Parent-records that are actually being deleted using a list and "IN :parentIds".

**Example:**

```
trigger ParentTrigger on Parent__c (before delete) {
    List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Parent__c p : Trigger.Old)
        parentIds.add(p.Id);

    Map<Id, List<Child__c>> childMap = new Map<Id, List<Child__c>>();
    for (Child__c child : [SELECT id, Parent__c FROM Child__c WHERE Parent__c IN :parentIds]) {
        if(!childMap.containsKey(child.Parent__c))
            childMap.put(child.Parent__c, new List<Child__c>());
        childMap.get(child.Parent__c).add(child);
    }

    for (Parent__c par : Trigger.Old) {
        if (childMap.containsKey(child.Parent__c)) {
            par.adderror('Cannot be deleted');
        }
    }
}
```

*Keep in mind that I typed the code in a textbox, tell me if it doesn't work.*

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Id,Parent__c> parMap = new Map<Id,Parent__c>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id from Child__r) from Parent__c WHERE ID IN: oldMap.keyset()]);
    for(Parent__c parent : oldList){
        if(parMap.containskey(parent.Id)){
            if(parMap.get(parent.Id).Child__r.size() > 0){
                parent.addError('Parent can not be deleted as its having child records' );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using trigger.

Try the following trigger example,

```
trigger ParentTrigger on Parent__c (before delete) {

Set pCIds = new Set();

Set<Id> pIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Parent__c p : Trigger.Old){

    pIds.add(p.Id);

}

for(Child__c C : [select id, parent__c, parent__r.Id from Child__c where parent__c =: pIds])

    {

    pCIds.add(C.parent__r.Id);

}

for(Parent__c objParent : Trigger.Old){

    if(pCIds.contains(objParent.Id)){

        objParent.adderror('OMG CHILD HAI RE USKE MAT KAR DELETE');

    }

}
}
```

The above trigger will execute while you try to delete a record that has a child records exist.

Hope this will help you...!

don't forget to mark best answer...